# Use `ffplay` to play images in a folder by file orders

Tags: video, ffmpeg, image-processing, image-viewers

`ffplay` is a tool to play images inside a folder without saving a video. See command [options](https://avpres.net/FFmpeg/play_sq.html) here

But the problem is the filenames in my folder do not have a pattern, as they are sampled unevenly.

Let's consider a worst case

```
./myfolder
./myfolder/1.jpg
./myfolder/5.jpg
./myfolder/132.jpg
./myfolder/2699.jpg
./myfolder/121484.jpg
./myfolder/223655.jpg
...
```

How to play those images by the order generated from the system (file order)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `mpv` to play, `find` to list the images, and `sort` to provide version/natural order.

```
mpv --mf-fps=25 mf://@<(find . -name '*.jpg' -print | sort -V)
```

This method has the added advantage of allowing seeking unlike `ffplay`.

Comment: This works. Is it btw possible to show the filename of the current frame? Or, current frame/all frames?

Comment: @NathanExplosion `--osd-playing-msg='${filename}'` would normally do it, but it does not appear to work in this case. I don't have a solution for that. Worth asking as a new question since it's different enough from the original question.